# Moment generating function for product states

Tags: probability-distributions, quantum-mechanics, generating-functions, large-deviations

In the sequel $B=M_\ell(\mathbb{C})$.
For $M\in\mathbb{N}$ fixed and $N\geq M$ I consider the symmetrizer $\pi_{M,N}(x_M)\in B^{\otimes N}$, which is the symmetrized tensor product of $a_1$,...,$a_M$ non-trivial matrices in $B$ to which we add $N-M$ identity matrices $I_\ell$, yielding therefore a tensor of total length $N$, which we then completely symmetrize and normalize.

NB: the case $M=1$ corresponds to the average of $x_1$ over $N$ copies of $B$.

I then consider the following function

\begin{align}
\mathbb{R}\ni t\mapsto\frac{1}{N}\log\int_{\omega\in S(B)} d\mu(\omega)\omega^N(e^{t N\pi_{M,N}(x_M)}), \ \ \ (*)
\end{align}

where $\omega\in S(B)$ is a (necessarily tracial) state on $B$, $\mu$ a probability measure on the state space $S(B)$, and $\omega^N$ denotes the $N$-fold product state with itself.

Iam interested in proving the existence and differentiability of the $N\to\infty$ limit  of (*) for arbitrary $M$.

I am able to do this only in the case $M=1$, because all terms occurring in $\pi_{1,N}(x_1)$ commute, so that the exponential splits.  For $M$ general, it becomes complicated since the individual terms occurring in $\pi_{M,N}(x_M)$ do not commute anymore. Does anyone no what to expect, or how to tackle this problem?

I thank you in advance for you comments.